# Problem accessing association from the result of a lambda query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

Has anyone had problems gettting associations to load using LINQ to SQL when your child record was loaded via a lambda query? For example:

```
var orderLine = db.OrderLines.
    Where(ol => ol.ID == orderLineID select ol).
    First();
// navigate to order via the association
var order = orderLine.GetOrder();
```

What I get basically is a null result from GetOrder().

But if I do this instead:

```
var orderLine = (from ol in db.OrderLines where ol.ID == orderLineID).First();
var order = orderLine.GetOrder();
```

Works fine.

What can cause this? Is this a bug?

**EDIT: Here's the actual code that WORKS with the Lambda expression commented out that DOESN'T WORK**

```
var msg = db.Messages.Where(m => m.ID == msgID).First();
if (msg.SentTS.HasValue) return;

// Get the message recipients
// I don't get it.. why doesn't lambda expressions work here? returns 0 results!
// var testtos = msg.GetMessageTos.Where(mt => mt.Active);
var tos = from mt in db.MessagesTos
          where mt.Active && mt.MessageID == msgID
          select mt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my EDIT for the code that works. I guess sometimes the "Answer" is to do what works, not necessarily what you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, I think it's a little cleaner.

```
var orderLine = db.OrderLines.Single( ol => ol.ID == orderLineID ); 
var order = orderLine.GetOrder();
```

I beileive in your non-working example you want to use `.First()` instead of `.Single()`.

Comment: please see my edit with the actual code that doesn't work (commented out). thanks!

Comment: What is the return types from `msg.GetMessageTos` and `db.MessageTos`? Also what type is `msg` and `db`? Does this work: `var tos = db.MessagesTos.Where( mt => mt.Active && mt.MessageID == msgID ).First();`

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? If so, how is msgID set? You may be running into a access closure problem.

Comment: testtos has the type IEnumerable<MessagesTo>, whereas tos has type type IQueryable<MessagesTo>.... msg is of type Message (a linq to sql class), and db is a subclass of System.Data.Linq.DataContext. I do believe var tos = db.MessagesTos.Where(mt => mt.Active && mt.MessageID == msg); would work. It only seems to be when accessing an association when the original query was done using a lambda exp.

Comment: No, it is not called from inside a loop. msgID is set as such from another function:
db.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(msg);
db.SubmitChanges();
msgID = msg.ID;

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem has more to do with the association than lambda expressions.

In your scenario, this should work:

```
var tos = db.MessagesTos.Where(mt=> mt.Active && mt.MessageID);
```

while this won't:

```
var tos = from mt in msg.SentTS
          where mt.Active
          select mt;
```

As to why it doesn't work, I suggest taking a look at the association in the designer and checking its matching the db model correctly (matching the correct columns). I also suggest to confirm that msg.SentTS is effectively coming empty, regardless of any further query you run on it.

Comment: Yes, it does match the db model correctly. I also moved some of the code to a test page and it works correctly, including the lambda query.  So I think it might have something to do with the datacontext caching the object graph or something weird to do with the use of TransactionScope.  Right now, I'm going to just leave it alone... It works. Thanks for your input.